# sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: django_content_type

Tags: python, django

I am trying to run app not written by me app.
When I write
`python manage.py makemigrations`
I got:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\direwolf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 64, in execute
        return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
      File "C:\Users\direwolf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 337, in execute
        return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
    sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: django_content_type

    The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
        execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
      File "C:\Users\direwolf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 367, in execute_from_command_line
        utility.execute()
      File "C:\Users\direwolf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 341, in execute
        django.setup()
      File "C:\Users\direwolf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 27, in setup
        apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
      File "C:\Users\direwolf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 115, in populate
        app_config.ready()
      File "C:\Users\direwolf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\apps.py", line 23, in ready
        self.module.autodiscover()
      File "C:\Users\direwolf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\__init__.py", line 26, in autodiscover
        autodiscover_modules('admin', register_to=site)
      File "C:\Users\direwolf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\module_loading.py", line 50, in autodiscover_modules
        import_module('%s.%s' % (app_config.name, module_to_search))
      File "C:\Users\direwolf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
        return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 978, in _gcd_import
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 205, in _call_with_frames_removed
      File "C:\Users\direwolf\Documents\web\python\alexbog80-motivity-3e5c21f03b3e\app\motivity\admin.py", line 23, in <module>
        admin.site.register(Offer, OfferAdmin)
      File "C:\Users\direwolf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\sites.py", line 110, in register
        system_check_errors.extend(admin_obj.check())
      File "C:\Users\direwolf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 117, in check
        return self.checks_class().check(self, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\direwolf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\checks.py", line 520, in check
        errors.extend(self._check_list_display(admin_obj))
      File "C:\Users\direwolf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\checks.py", line 596, in _check_list_display
        for index, item in enumerate(obj.list_display)
      File "C:\Users\direwolf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\checks.py", line 596, in <listcomp>
        for index, item in enumerate(obj.list_display)
      File "C:\Users\direwolf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\checks.py", line 604, in _check_list_display_item
        elif hasattr(model, item):
      File "C:\Users\direwolf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\tagging\fields.py", line 55, in __get__
        return edit_string_for_tags(Tag.objects.usage_for_model(owner))
      File "C:\Users\direwolf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\tagging\models.py", line 157, in usage_for_model
        usage = self.usage_for_queryset(queryset, counts, min_count)
      File "C:\Users\direwolf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\tagging\models.py", line 183, in usage_for_queryset
        extra_joins, extra_criteria, params)
      File "C:\Users\direwolf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\tagging\models.py", line 113, in _get_usage
        'content_type_id': ContentType.objects.get_for_model(model).pk,
      File "C:\Users\direwolf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\contenttypes\models.py", line 52, in get_for_model
        ct = self.get(app_label=opts.app_label, model=opts.model_name)
      File "C:\Users\direwolf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
        return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\direwolf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 379, in get
        num = len(clone)
      File "C:\Users\direwolf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 238, in __len__
        self._fetch_all()
      File "C:\Users\direwolf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1087, in _fetch_all
        self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())
      File "C:\Users\direwolf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 54, in __iter__
        results = compiler.execute_sql()
      File "C:\Users\direwolf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 835, in execute_sql
        cursor.execute(sql, params)
      File "C:\Users\direwolf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 79, in execute
        return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
      File "C:\Users\direwolf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 64, in execute
        return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
      File "C:\Users\direwolf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 94, in __exit__
        six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
      File "C:\Users\direwolf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\six.py", line 685, in reraise
        raise value.with_traceback(tb)
      File "C:\Users\direwolf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 64, in execute
        return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
      File "C:\Users\direwolf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 337, in execute
        return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
    django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: django_content_type
```

What do I do?

upd 1:
`python manage.py migrate` traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\direwolf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\direwolf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 337, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: django_content_type

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\direwolf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 367, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\direwolf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 341, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "C:\Users\direwolf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 27, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\direwolf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 115, in populate
    app_config.ready()
  File "C:\Users\direwolf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\apps.py", line 23, in ready
    self.module.autodiscover()
  File "C:\Users\direwolf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\__init__.py", line 26, in autodiscover
    autodiscover_modules('admin', register_to=site)
  File "C:\Users\direwolf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\module_loading.py", line 50, in autodiscover_modules
    import_module('%s.%s' % (app_config.name, module_to_search))
  File "C:\Users\direwolf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 978, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 205, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\direwolf\Documents\web\python\alexbog80-motivity-3e5c21f03b3e\app\motivity\admin.py", line 23, in <module>
    admin.site.register(Offer, OfferAdmin)
  File "C:\Users\direwolf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\sites.py", line 110, in register
    system_check_errors.extend(admin_obj.check())
  File "C:\Users\direwolf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 117, in check
    return self.checks_class().check(self, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\direwolf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\checks.py", line 520, in check
    errors.extend(self._check_list_display(admin_obj))
  File "C:\Users\direwolf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\checks.py", line 596, in _check_list_display
    for index, item in enumerate(obj.list_display)
  File "C:\Users\direwolf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\checks.py", line 596, in <listcomp>
    for index, item in enumerate(obj.list_display)
  File "C:\Users\direwolf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\checks.py", line 604, in _check_list_display_item
    elif hasattr(model, item):
  File "C:\Users\direwolf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\tagging\fields.py", line 55, in __get__
    return edit_string_for_tags(Tag.objects.usage_for_model(owner))
  File "C:\Users\direwolf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\tagging\models.py", line 157, in usage_for_model
    usage = self.usage_for_queryset(queryset, counts, min_count)
  File "C:\Users\direwolf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\tagging\models.py", line 183, in usage_for_queryset
    extra_joins, extra_criteria, params)
  File "C:\Users\direwolf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\tagging\models.py", line 113, in _get_usage
    'content_type_id': ContentType.objects.get_for_model(model).pk,
  File "C:\Users\direwolf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\contenttypes\models.py", line 52, in get_for_model
    ct = self.get(app_label=opts.app_label, model=opts.model_name)
  File "C:\Users\direwolf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\direwolf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 379, in get
    num = len(clone)
  File "C:\Users\direwolf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 238, in __len__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "C:\Users\direwolf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1087, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())
  File "C:\Users\direwolf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 54, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql()
  File "C:\Users\direwolf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 835, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\direwolf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 79, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\direwolf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\direwolf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 94, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "C:\Users\direwolf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "C:\Users\direwolf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\direwolf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 337, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils
```

.OperationalError: no such table: django_content_type

Upd 2:
Offer class in `models.py`

```
class Offer(TimeStampMixin, SEOFieldsMixin):
    title = models.CharField(u'Название предложения', max_length=255, blank=False)
    discription = models.TextField(u'Красивое описание оффера', null=False, blank=False)
    cover = models.ImageField(u'Обложка', blank=False, null=False)
    tags = TagAutocompleteField(blank=False, verbose_name='Теги')
    active = models.BooleanField(u'Активный?', default=True)
    publish = models.BooleanField(u'Показывать на сайте?', default=True)

    def preview_image(self):
        # try:
        thumbnail = get_thumbnail(self.cover, 'x50', crop='center')
        # except TypeError:
        #     return u'Нет картинки'
        # except:
        #     return u'Нет картинки'  # if original img not exist
        return '<a href="%s/"><img src="%s"/></a>' % (self.id, thumbnail.url)

    preview_image.short_description = u'Обложка'
    preview_image.allow_tags = True

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = u'Предложение'
        verbose_name_plural = u'Предложения'
        ordering  = ('-modified_value',)
        get_latest_by = 'created_value'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % self.title
```

I didn't find admin class
only this:

```
from django.contrib import admin

from app.motivity.models import TaskOffer, Offer, UserOffers

class TaskOfferAdmin(admin.TabularInline):
    model = TaskOffer
    exclude = ['meta_title', 'meta_description', 'meta_keywords']


class OfferAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['preview_image','title','tags', 'publish']
    list_display_links = ['title']
    list_filter = ['tags']
    inlines = [TaskOfferAdmin, ]
    fields = ['title', 'discription', 'cover', 'tags']


class UserOfferAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass

admin.site.register(UserOffers, UserOfferAdmin)
admin.site.register(Offer, OfferAdmin)
```

Comment: show `Offer` and `OfferAdmin` class, please

Comment: did you run `python manage.py migrate`?

Comment: @eyllanesc see upd

Comment: @user3148949 see update #1

Comment: Is `'django.contrib.contenttypes'` in your `INSTALLED_APPS` in `settings.py`?

Comment: @Evert yeah....

Comment: what is your django version?

Comment: @MithileshGupta >>> django.VERSION
(1, 10, 6, 'final', 0)

Comment: can you delete the db and try again?

Comment: Try running makemigrations on only `django_content_type`  app

Comment: @MosesKoledoye how do I do this? I have only one app called motivit

Comment: @MithileshGupta  tried deleting - the same error

Comment: Since you apparently don't have any data in your DB, try squashing (deleting) all your migrations and creating fresh ones with `makemigrations`

Answer (score 4):

This issue can occur if you have code that uses contenttypes database information at import time rather than at runtime. For example, if you added code that runs at the module level or class level along the lines of:

```
TERM_CONTENT_TYPE = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(Term)
```

but you only added this *after* running your initial migrations that created that content type tables, then the next person who runs the migrations on a fresh database will get this error.

In this case the solution is to move code like that into places that runs only when a method is called, like into a view or other method.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue while using **Python 3.6.5** and **Django==2.1.7** on **Mac OS 10.15.2**. I fixed it by manually creating the table `django_content_type` with the columns: `id, app_label, model`

On running `python manage.py migrate` and the error appears, there should be a `*.sqlite3` file created on the path specified on the `DATABASE` key within your `settings.py` file.

**Example:**

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'base_site.sqlite3'),
    }
}
```

My Sqlite DB filename is `base_site.sqlite3` and is created at the `BASE_DIR` of the project.

**Steps to follow:**

- Connect to the created SQLite DB using:

  ```
  sqlite3 <DB filename>
  ```
- Create the table using the following command:

  ```
  CREATE TABLE IF
  NOT EXISTS "django_content_type" (
   "id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
   "app_label" varchar(100) NOT NULL,
   "model" varchar(100) NOT NULL
  );
  ```
- Finally run the migrations using the command below:

  ```
  python manage.py migrate --fake-initial
  ```

  This should run the migrations as expected.

Comment: Different versions but this fixed my issue. The funny thing is when I ran `python manage.py migrate` after creating the table, it complained about it already existing (so yeah, you do really need the --fake-initial). Weird bug..

Answer (score 3):

For test database easy fix can be:

```
# Remove database and the history  cache for of applied migrations
rm db.sqlite3
find . | grep "__pycache__" | xargs sudo rm -rf

# Check that migration are not applied
python manage.py showmigrations

# Then apply fisrt only the admin module migrations
python manage.py migrate admin

# Then apply all others
python manage.py migrate
```

I think it should be good pratice to always apply admin migrations at first then others later.

Answer (score 2):

simply delete your db.sqlite3 file....and reagain run the command--->
py manage.py migrate
then,
py manage.py makemigrations app_name
finally,
py manage.py migrate...
follow this process wish you will fixed your prblm

Answer (score -1):

It seems like I was using python 3x
And this app was written using python 2x